# ggpairs returns Error in x$widths : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Tags: r, ggally

I am using RStudio 0.98.978, and GGally 0.4.7.

I am trying to use [ggpairs](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/GGally/docs/ggpairs), from the package GGally. Even when I attempt the most basic examples I receive the following error:

> Error in x$widths : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

An example code is below:

```
data(tips)
ggpairs(tips[,1:2])
```

I have also tried even simpler codes such as,

```
c1 <- c(sample(1:20, 10,))
c2 <- c(sample(1:20, 10,))
c3 <- c(sample(1:20, 10,))
d <- data.frame(c1,c2,c3)

ggpairs(d)
```

The basic "pairs" function works fine,

```
pairs(d)
```

When searching for solutions I learned why the error normally arises (when trying to use indexing on a function), but I have not found any information on this particular problem. Any insights would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I am using R 3.1.0 Patched (2014-04-10 r65396), RStudio 0.98.507, and GGally 0.4.7.

I suggest that you first reinstall `GGally`.

The following code that you had has the following error:

```
data(tips)
# Warning message:
# In data(tips) : data set ‘tips’ not found
```

But, the following code does work:

```
data(tips, package = "reshape")
ggpairs(tips[,1:2])
```

I found the correct way to obtain the tips data from the [GGally documentation](http://cran.revolutionanalytics.com/web/packages/GGally/GGally.pdf)

I had success with the rest of the code that you provided.

Thank you.

Comment: I re-installed GGally and it's extensions, and the ggpairs worked fine. I had install.packages("GGally") in an if statement, so I had not been re-installing as I had thought.

Comment: @ScottW I am glad that you were able to get GGally to work properly.